# Не работает планировщик задач Openserver

Tags: php, cron, openserver

Не могу разобраться с планировщиком задач. По статьям в интернете прописываю вот так, так же пробовал и другие варианты, они тоже не работают. Это лог выполнения крона, по нему можно все понять

> 04 Aug 17:06:00 Start:
> c:\openserver\ospanel\modules\php\PHP_7.1-x64\php-win.exe -c
> c:\openserver\ospanel\userdata\temp\config\php.ini -q -f
> c:\openserver\ospanel\domains\localhost\test.php
>
> 04 Aug 17:06:00 Start:
> c:\openserver\ospanel\modules\php\PHP_7.1-x64\php-win.exe -c
> C:\OpenServer\OSPanel\modules\php\PHP_7.1-x64\php.ini -q -f
> c:\openserver\ospanel\domains\localhost\test.php
>
> 04 Aug 17:06:00 Start result: 0
>
> 04 Aug 17:06:00 Start result: 0

Кстати, папки c:\openserver\ospanel\userdata\temp\config\ у меня почему-то нет, не знаю должна ли быть, поэтому пробовал еще и вторым вариантом

Для примера исполняемого скрипта я взял код прямо с гайда, в будущем заменю на свой

```
<?php 

// строка, которую будем записывать
$text = date("F j, Y, g:i a")." CRON отработал\n";
 
//Открываем файл
$fp = fopen("test.txt", "a+");
 
// записываем в файл текст
fwrite($fp, $text);
 
// закрываем
fclose($fp);

?>
```

Если выполнить его через браузер, то скрипт отрабатывает и создается запись в файле, через крон ничего не создается

Comment: Что значит не работает, как вы это определяете? Если по коду 0, то это стандартный код успешного завершения консольного приложения и не является показателем. Приведите код файла и то, что должно быть достигнуто для успешного или неуспешного результата.

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос, добавил пример исполняемого скрипта

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример записи в cron:

```
"%progdir%\modules\php\%phpdriver%\php-win.exe" -c 
"%progdir%\modules\php\%phpdriver%\php.ini" -q -f "C:\Server\domains\test\index.php"
```

А вот какой должен быть PHP файл:

```
<?php 

// строка, которую будем записывать
$text = date("F j, Y, g:i a")." CRON отработал\n";
 
//Открываем файл
$fp = fopen("C:\\Server\\domains\\test\\test.txt", "a+");
 
// записываем в файл текст
fwrite($fp, $text);
 
// закрываем
fclose($fp);

?>
```

Почему-то переменные директорий не работают (`getcwd()`, `__DIR__` и другие)

**Обновление**

При cron'е установленном для использования php (а не php-win) работает как нужно:

```
"%progdir%\modules\php\%phpdriver%\php.exe" -c 
"%progdir%\modules\php\%phpdriver%\php.ini" -q -f 
"C:\Server\domains\test\index.php"
```

Файл:

```
<?php 

// строка, которую будем записывать
$text = date("F j, Y, g:i a")." CRON отработал\n";
 
//Открываем файл
$fp = fopen(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "test.txt", "a+");
 
// записываем в файл текст
fwrite($fp, $text);
 
// закрываем
fclose($fp);

?>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Работает

Comment: @ИгорьМихайлов в таком случае пометьте мой ответ как подходящий вам