# Как запустить Telegram Bot`а CRON`ом

Tags: php, telegram-bot, curl, php-curl

Столкнулся с проблемой когда начал вешать бота ТГ на крон.

Проблема: при обращение крон к файлу где лежит логика бота сообщение в телеграмм не отправляется, а вот если обратится к скрипту из браузере то все отправляет.

Ниже функция отправки сообщения в телеграмм

```
$apiURL = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' . TELEGRAM_TOKEN;
$url  = $apiURL. "/sendPhoto?chat_id=" . TELEGRAM_CHATID;
$post_fields = array('chat_id' => TELEGRAM_CHATID,
    'caption' => $message,
    'photo' => new CURLFile(realpath('content/'.$image_name))
);
$ch = curl_init();

/*curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Content-Type:multipart/form-data"
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);*/

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ($post_fields));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$output = curl_exec($ch);
```

Подскажите пожалуйста решение или куда копать.

ЗЫЖ Хотя в OpenServer работает крон

Спасибо.

Comment: Вероятно дубликат [проблемы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1162051/Не-работает-планировщик-задач-openserver/1162552#1162552) с настройкой крона в OpenServer?

Comment: в openserver CRON работает и скрипт отправляет сообщение в телеграмм, а вот на хостинге CRON отрабатывает но сообщение в телеграмм не доходят

Comment: Добавьте логирование, результат исполнения curl_exec и посмотрите что в итоге. Пропингуйте с сервера ваш адрес для начала - в общем, выполните шаги, которые покажут вам есть ли препятствия на сервере для достижения сообщений цели.

Comment: Обращение к скрипту через крон выдает (побывал через /cron-job.org) Failed 403 Forbidden, а включить ЛОГ на сервере не получилось